# What is the point of adding short sleep to while true loop?

Tags: python, loops

Across the internet, I've saw several examples of handling a service, which awaits for messages from clients in an endless loop, including a short sleep. Example:

```
while True:
    check_messages_stack()
    sleep(0.1)
```

What's the point of the sleep there? Is it supposed to save resources? If it does save some resources, would it be a meaningful amount?

Comment: Question is not really meaningful without context and specifics.

Comment: For less cpu cycles. Run a while loop `while True:pass` and `while True:pass;sleep(.1)`, you will see a difference in your cpu usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sleep` doesn't use CPU resources, but constantly executing `check_messages_stack()` might (depending what you have there) so if you don't need to do it constantly it is a good practice to give CPU some time off.

Answer (score 2):

While your PC is running, your CPU needs to execute a lot of process (to make your PC run). 
As CPUs are extremly fast they can fake to do multiple tasks at the same time but they don't really do (nowadays we get multiple cores CPU and mutithreading but forget about it for this explaination).
They just execute some part of a process during a certain amount of time then a part of an other process then go back to the first and so on.

In a simple way, the CPU is allow to switch to one process to another when it is not used by the process it actualy runing, for instance when the process does some I/O or waiting for user interaction.

When you do a `while true` it will loop ASAP it finished to execute the function in the `while` loop. Here ASAP realy mean ASAP, so no other process would be able to do anything in between of two loops. Because the CPU is continously processing.

When you put a `sleep` you allow the CPU to let other process to be executed. There is no really mater of how long the sleep is because a random CPU can do billions of operations in a microsecond.

So in your question, the `sleep(0.1)` allows your CPU to execute somme bilions operations in between of two `check_messages_stack()` call.

For more information, looking for "CPU Scheduling".

Answer (score 1):

`sleep` like the others have said relaxes the CPU usage, but in addition if it's something like accessing network/web data the sleep is needed to not crash the host server and ban you.

Answer (score 0):

If the function doesn't wait for anything, it would consume 100% CPU, by adding that sleep, it gives the CPU some time to execute other processes